# Java - Jsoup How would I extract the title and link in this HTML code?

Tags: java, jsoup

I would like to extract the title `"Syrian arch razed by ISIS and re-created with 3D "` in this HTML code, along with its link `"http://www.theverge.com/2016/9/19/12972504/palmyra-arch-of-triumph-isis-3d-replica-new-york-city"` from the google news site: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=technology

I would really appreciate your help, thanks,

Sorry I have to have an image but StackOverflow was formatting the code weirdly

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4LxE.png)

Comment: If it's formatting the code weirdly, wrap it in a code block (add a blank line before the code and add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line of code; can also be done by selecting the code and pressing `CTRL+K`)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you visit this [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/) and experiment with this

```
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Get the html document title
            title = document.title();
            Element link = document.select("a.l _HId");
            String s1 = link.absUrl("src"); //Gives you link
            String s2 = link.text(); //Gives you Required text
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```